# Opera does not want to update one RSS feed

Tags: opera, rss

Opera for linux, 12.16

The feed: http://radiofrance-podcast.net/podcast09/rss_13364.xml

No matter if I suscribe to it or simply open the page as a web page, the 
most recent item I find is from 2014-02-02. I've tried with a clean 
personaldir too.

But with Firefox, for instance, there's a new item from 2014-02-09.

It seems Opera just refuses to update this feed. Why?

Comment: (I can confirm this behavior)

Comment: It's good to know that at least I'm not alone. Today, a new week has passed, so we have two new items in Firefox, but Opera remains stuck.

Comment: Today the new items appear in Opera. Maybe they've changed something in their server, because I haven't done anything different.